# how to bind the data returned by json to jquery gridview in asp.net?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, jquery-plugins, jqgrid-asp.net

How can i bind the data returned by json object d to jquery grid ? I have tried using asp.net gridview but failed. I have seen some links of jquery grid but no source code is available 
in my aspx this is what i have done:

```
function get(strcode) {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default.aspx/MyMethod",
        data: "{'Code':'" + strcode + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            // Here i want to bind the gridview to the values contained in d
            //also the values in d are dynamic means i am getting them from the datatable
        }
    });
}
```

Thank you. also i have  very confusion regarding jqgrid. is jqgrid is free and is jqgrid is client side or server side?

Comment: the data i am getting ie d is as follows: {"d":["1234567890-IndianJones"]}

Answer (score 0):

There are many jQuery plug-ins which you can use like

1. [jQuery DataTable](http://datatables.net/)
2. [JQ Grid](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html)

You can visit there site where you can get the example for Json data as well.